# Best practice to reduce generic variables in type hierarchies?

Tags: java, generics

I'm wondering if it is possible to make java's generics more readable and/or easier to use when having type-hierarchies and many generic-variables included. I'm not really familiar with java's generics yet. What can be done in the following example:

Let's assume I need the following class...

```
abstract class BaseClass<T> {}
```

... to work with Lists of the following class ...

```
class Foo<T1, T2> {}
```

... and additionally provoding an iterator over such instances.

So i would do the following:

```
class ImplClass<T1, T2> extends BaseClass<List<Foo<T1, T2>>> implements Iterator<Foo<T1, T2>> {}
```

Let's also assume there is an interface dealing with the BaseClass:

```
interface Manipulator<T, B extends BaseClass<T>> {
  void doSomething(B baseClassInstance);
}
```

So when writing a classes implementing that interface for the ImplClass i would always have to write that whole generic-signature again, don't i?
So something like:

```
class ManipulatorA<T1, T2> implements Manipulator<List<Foo<T1, T2>>, ImplClass<T1, T2>> {
  @Override
  void doSomething(ImplClass<T1, T2> baseClassInstance) {...}
}
class ManipulatorB<T1, T2> implements Manipulator<List<Foo<T1, T2>>, ImplClass<T1, T2>> {
  @Override
  void doSomething(ImplClass<T1, T2> baseClassInstance) {...}
}
```

So instead i could provide an EMPTY interface which is just for the type-conversion to reduce the generic variables:

```
interface ImplManipulator<T1, T2> extends Manipulator<List<Foo<T1, T2>>, ImplClass<T1, T2>>{
  // actually empty
}
```

and the implementations would look like:

```
class ManipulatorA<T1, T2> implements ImplManipulator<T1, T2> {
  @Override
  void doSomething(ImplClass<T1, T2> baseClassInstance) {...}
}
class ManipulatorB<T1, T2> implements ImplManipulator<T1, T2> {
  @Override
  void doSomething(ImplClass<T1, T2> baseClassInstance) {...}
}
```

Having a bunch of empty interfaces seems like not really readable to me. 
Having to think about huge generic signatures all the time neither.
What can i do to produce better code when dealing with such situation?

Comment: Is the `Foo<T1, T2>` constant factor in this scenario or do you want to declare e.g. `BaseClass<List<String>>` as well?

Comment: Well Foo<T1, T2> is just an example for a very often used type. But it's not a constant factor, so i might also go with an additional intermediate-class ListBaseClass<T> extends BaseClass<List<T>> implements Iterable<T> as well and provide an additional (empty) interface for that. Still wouldn't change much i guess.

Answer (score 0):

> What can i do to produce better code when dealing with such situation?

change the language...

java doesn't support type aliases or haskell-style new types.  if you can, add scala to your project. you can mix scala and java.

another option would be to use some kind of source generation/preprocessing. maybe even using AST transformers. but it would be totally custom so it's hard to give you any advice without knowing exactly your case

if you have to stick with java then, as you noticed, the only way to alias generic types is to create an intermediary interface or a class. You can clean it a little by:

- naming them correctly. `ImplManipulator` doesn't give you much information but `FooListManipulator` may be helpful
- place them correctly. if you create only inner subclasses then don't make new file with empty interface - place it in the same file where subclasses are. if you create subclasses only in one package, create a class `TypeAliases` and place them all your interfaces with package scoppe. if you need it globally, create a package `typeAliases`, put everything there and never ever look there again

another option is to simply drop generics. people do it often with hamcrest matchers because their long signatures kill readability. after all generics are to help you, not to make your life harder (at least that was the idea)